# Why is attic wire controlled by two circuit breakers?

Tags: electrical, ceiling-fan

I live in a condo built in the late 70s.  I'm installing a ceiling fan in the master bedroom and need to run electricity to it.  I went in the attic and there is an existing romex wire near the location of the fan that I thought I might tap into.   I turned off the master bedroom circuit breaker to see if that wire was on the bedroom circuit, and the wire was still live.  To make a long story short, I turned off and on each circuit in the house, and nothing killed the power in the wire!   I finally find out that I had to turn off the master bedroom circuit breaker, and also the circuit breaker for the den next door in order to get the non-contact voltage tester to stop beeping.  All the lights and outlets in the bedroom and den behave as expected (when I turn off the bedroom circuit breaker all the bedroom lights and outlets go off, and when I turn off the den circuit breaker all the den light and outlets go off).

So why is this wire in the attic controlled by two circuit breakers?  Is this normal?  I believe it's a typical 12-2 wire (all wires in house are 12 gauge).  Are both wires (black and white) hot?   Bad idea to tap into this wire (adding a junction box) to run electricity to my future ceiling fan?

Comment: Do you have a small incandescent night-light and a receptacle you can temporarily attach to those wires while they are dead, and then turn them back on again?

Comment: Is it a 3 wire cable (red, black, white, ground)? Sometimes two opposing voltage lines are run together and share the identified(white) conductor for a return path.  If it's only a 2 wire cable(B,W,G), in all likelihood you have a cross between two circuits of the same phase.  If the latter is the case it should be corrected as it could result in conductors carrying more than their rated current.

Comment: Could be that in a switch box somewhere that has devices on multiple circuits the neutrals got mismatched, resulting in the neutral in this cable/circuit also functioning as a neutral in another circuit. Which is *not a good thing*.

Comment: Thanks for the responses.       I'm sure it's a 2 wire cable (B,W,G), it's stamped on the wire.       I had the whole panel replaced recently when I moved in the house as I had a Federated panel which was flagged by the home inspector.  Sounds like I might have a wiring problem in the circuit panel.  Is this something I could easily see if I take off the cover?

Comment: It's possible you're seeing [phantom voltage](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stray_voltage#Coupled_voltages).  If so it will likely disappear if you plug a load into the circuit while it's disconnected.